I unable to found old jar version give specific link
I need realm-gradle-plugin-6.0.1.jar file for compile my old project no need to update to current version. because  update to latest then so many errors.

This question is similar to: Cant find realm dependency. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

JCenter has been decommissioned.  Recent versions of realm-gradle-plugin are available from Maven Central.  However, if you really need a version of realm-gradle-plugin older than 10.4.0, you have a problem since they is not available from Maven Central.
Here's the advice from JFrog - the folks who ran JCenter:

What should a user do if a package they need is not available in Maven
Central?
If a specific package version you need is not available on Maven
Central, you have the following options:

Contact the package owner and request that they make it available on Maven Central
Check for a more recent version of the package on Maven Central
Remove your dependency on the package
Copy the package to your organization’s internal repository

If you are a JFrog user, and none of these options work for you,
please reach out to support@jfrog.com.

My advice would be to try updating the realm-gradle-plugin dependency in your project's Gradle file to the latest version; i.e. option 2.
I don't think option 1 will have any effect.  (I assume that people will have already asked the io.realm maintainers to upload older versions.)  Option 3 is not feasible.  Option 4 is clunky, but I guess you could do that if you can't get option 2 to work.

The JAR you need is available here at Maven Central.  Looks like the file isn't available if you click on the link.
If you aren't using Maven, you should be.
You should upgrade.   That JAR is five years old.  There's a new version 10.19.0 available.  No reason to stay behind.   Fix the errors and retire some technical debt.
I see two vulnerabilities associated with the newest JAR.   I'll bet those problems and more exist in the old version.  Failing to upgrade can be a security disaster.   Don't put it off.
